# Don't show android native autofill save dialog if credentials already there in password manager

Tags: android, android-autofill-manager

I am seeing android autofill native save password dialog again and again even credentials are same. how to avoid it?
Show autofill native save password dialog only if credentials are different

Use Case:- lets say I had save  username- dummy@b.m  and password- 123456 now again I am login using same credentials than I should not see save dialog.

[Attaching video for reference](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N2mrvnXhlyMT-79GL4dSKQoJeWBw64vi/view?usp=sharing)